# How to call a function to provide a response instead of an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm relatively new to JSON, it's been a while since I've dabbled in JavaScript.
Using W3Schools tryit editor I have a script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Convert a JSON string into a JavaScript object.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const myJSON = '{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}';
const myData = {
    firstname: "deadly",
    lastname: "buzz",
    age: 23,
    city: "Limerick"
    };
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myData.firstname;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I want my element to refer to `fullname` instead of `firstname`
I want to update my JSON object to look something like

```
const myData = {
    firstname: "deadly",
    lastname: "buzz",
    age: 23,
    city: "Limerick",
    fullname: function(){
       return firstname +" " + lastname;
        }
    };
```

and then call my page like:

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myData.fullname;`
which would hopefully output the same as a JSON object outlined like:

```
const myData = {
    firstname: "deadly",
    lastname: "buzz",
    age: 23,
    city: "Limerick",
    fullname: "deadlybuzz"
    };
```

But I cannot find anywhere this would work or how to reference this.  I'm finding some of the tutorials and references confusing and overwhelming to get to the actual answer of how to do this (or if I can).

Can someone help, either to point to where I can find clean concise references or provide an answer please.

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? You are not using `myObj`, the parsed `myJSON`! The `myData` that you *are* using is just an object literal.

Comment: Calling a function requires `()`, so that would have to be `innerHTML = myData.fullname();` then. (And btw., that mydata you have there would not be a "JSON object". JSON can not contain functions. And the O in JSON already stand for Object :-) And actual object never "is" JSON, only the representation of it _in code form_ is.)

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), and JSON doesn't allow for encoding functions.

Comment: You're looking to call `fullname` or make it a getter. Also you'll need to use `this` inside of it.

Comment: You may want to look into [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)...

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
    const myData = {
    firstname: "deadly",
    lastname: "buzz",
    age: 23,
    city: "Limerick",
    fullname: function(){
           return myData.firstname +" " + myData.lastname;
        }
    };


myData.fullname() // 'deadly buzz'
```

I added an image of the code in W3 Schools tryit editor, but the right answer and the perfect solution from  @aj-saleh [image: Image with the code in W3 Schools tryi]

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I'm trying to use the W3 Schools tryit editor and when I pass fullname  to the server it returns the string for the function instead.